# how to get sum of 2 lists index by index in python?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, string, list

for example i have two lists a and b and there's two or more lists in them(depends on my input)
i want the out put to be the sum of a[0] and b[0] and ...

```
n = int(input())
for i in range(n):
    x = list(map(int, input().split()))
    a.append(x)

for i in range(n):
    x2 = list(map(int, input().split()))
    b.append(x2)
```

now for example n = 2 and we will have 4 inputs after that
like:

```
these will be appended to a
1 2 3
4 5 6
and these two will be appended to b
2 3 4
5 6 7
```

now i want my output to be

```
3 5 7 
9 11 13 
as you can see a[0] + b[0]
and a[1] + b[1]
```

but i want my code to output like this even when i give my n input a number more than 2
for example if i give 3 to my n input i will have 3 indexes in a and b and they are all list and i want the output to work same as the last exaples,

```
example 
for n = 3
a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
b = [[3, 2, 1], [4, 5, 6], [9, 8, 7]]
```

Comment: can you add the expected output of the given example?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[[p[0]+p[1] for p in (zip(k[0],k[1]))] for k in list(zip(a,b))]
```

For

```
a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
b = [[3, 2, 1], [4, 5, 6], [9, 8, 7]]
```

It will give:

```
[[4, 4, 4], [8, 10, 12], [16, 16, 16]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[[i+j for i, j in zip(x, y) ] for x,y in zip(a, b)]
```

Comment: Please add some text to explain your answer.  Answers that are purely code are less useful than those that include an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this :

```
n = int(input())
a = []
b = []
for i in range(n):
    x = input().split()
    a.append(x)

for i in range(n):
    x2 = input().split()
    b.append(x2)

tabA = []
tabB = []

for l in range(len(a)):
    tabA.append([int(i) for i in a[l][0]])
    tabB.append([int(i) for i in b[l][0]])

print(tabA)
print(tabB)

print([[i+j for i, j in zip(x, y) ] for x,y in zip(tabA, tabB)])
```